# Not be able to install tabletext

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rajat\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.2', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "C:\Users\rajat\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "C:\Users\rajat\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2852, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "C:\Users\rajat\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2443, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "C:\Users\rajat\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2449, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "C:\Users\rajat\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip-1.5.2-py3.7.egg\pip\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.log import logger
  File "C:\Users\rajat\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip-1.5.2-py3.7.egg\pip\log.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import colorama, pkg_resources
  File "C:\Users\rajat\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip-1.5.2-py3.7.egg\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 1423, in <module>
    register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
```

Always getting error for this.

Comment: What is the command you are running?

Comment: I have run "Pip install tabletext" after downloading file and installing setup after that getting error source file loader error.

Comment: Can you share the entire error?

Comment: @RajatTiwari  Please add to your question details steps to how you reached this error, like 1. I run Pip install tabletext`  2. ...    Otherwise is very difficutl to help you. ALso share: Python version 2. OS and (if windows if is 32 bit por 64 bit) thank